# rust why does an early return from an unwrap_or() cause issues

Tags: rust, return

I am trying to solve problem 7 on leetcode. The problem is somewhat under specified but from an error from a previous submission it appears that any input that would result in an overflow should return 0. To account for that I replaced `pow` with `checked_pow` with the intention of using `unwrap_or`to early return if an overflow occurred. However, I now get a return of 0 for any input and a warning that any code following the call to `unwrap_or` is unreachable. Why is this?

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{}", reverse(-23));
    println!("{}", reverse(1534236469));
    println!("{}", reverse(1));
}

fn reverse(x: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut working = {
        if x > 0 {
            x
        } else {
            -x
        }
    };
    let mut digits = Vec::new();
    while working > 0 {
        digits.push(working % 10);
        working /= 10;
    }

    let result = digits
        .iter()
        .rev()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(power, x)| x * (10i32.checked_pow(power as u32).unwrap_or(return 0)))
        .sum();
    if x > 0 {
        result
    } else {
        -result
    }
}
```

P.S. I have previously realised there are far better ways of solving this problem so please don't comment saying my solution is bad (I know it is). However, I am posting the question as while it is far from ideal I still do not understand why it doesn't work. Thanks,

Comment: Just as a suggestion, "I am trying to solve problem 7 on leetcode" isn't something you should say on SO - state the problem you're trying to solve, don't ask people to look it up on an external site (or assume that site will still have the same problem 7 if and when someone looks up your answer.) In this case it wasn't really an issue since you had a standalone code bug, but in that case it's jut needless context that complicates the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return in Rust is [an expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/return-expr.html) which breaks control flow of a function and makes it return early. As read in The Rust Reference:

> Return expressions are denoted with the keyword return. Evaluating a return expression moves its argument into the designated output location for the current function call, destroys the current function activation frame, and transfers control to the caller frame.

Consider following example:

```rust
pub fn foo(val: Option<i32>) -> i32 {
    val.unwrap_or(return 0)
}
```

`Option::<T>::unwrap_or` takes a value `T` and returns it in the case of `None` variant. What is important is that compiler will evaluate passed expression **before** checking if `Option` is `None`. When the compiler tries to evaluate passed expression it encounters `return` keyword, which tells it to return early from `foo` (note that this would be different in the case `val.unwrap_or_else(|| return 0)`, which takes a *closure* and calls it *after* encountering `None` variant).

You might ask why does Rust allow this, since `unwrap_or` expected an `i32` and none was given. Shouldn't this be a type mismatch? No. `return` expression (as well as `break` and `continue`) has type [never](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html) (also spelled as `!`), which can coerce to any other type (see linked documentation).

To summarize. `return` will return from the current function early and you probably want to just use `unwrap_or(0)`.

Comment: As to why `return` coerces to any type, this is important for things like conditionals and matches e.g. `let a = if thing { 0 } else { return 42; };` would not work if `return` was not compatible with values.